# Proving that the spectral radius of a nilpotent element of a Banach algebra is equal to zero.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, nilpotence

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with unit $e$ and let $a\in A$ be nilpotent. I want to show that the spectral radius $\rho(a)=0$.

We have that the spectral radius satisfies $$\rho(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a^{n}\|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\inf_{n\ge 1}\|a^{n}\|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Since $a$ is nilpotent, we have that $\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{n_{0}}=0$. Since $n_{0}\ne 0$, it follows that $\rho(a)=0$.

I feel that this proof is incomplete though.

Comment: Looks ok to me, if you want to explain why it follows you can say that it's by the definition of $\rho(a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good proof.

Here is another one. Assume that $a^m=0$. If you know that
$$
\sigma(a)=\{f(a):\ f \text{ is a multiplicative functional }\},
$$
then for any such $f$ we have $f(a)^m=f(a^m)=f(0)=0$. So $f(a)=0$, and then $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$.

Yet another proof, without machinery: if $a^m=0$, then $1-a$ is invertible: indeed, the inverse is $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{m-1}$, because
$$
(1-a)(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{m-1})=1.
$$
For any $\lambda\ne0$ as $a/\lambda$ is nilpotent, $\lambda-a=\lambda(1-a/\lambda)$ is invertible. Thus $\lambda$ is in the resolvent of $a$. As this works for any $\lambda\ne0$, we get that $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Martin Argerami, we have $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ $